# How to have the Button react on the Bindings Property Change change in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, button, event-handling, datacontext

I have a control that has a `DataContext` being loaded and based on it I create a bunch of `Button`s. I would like to have the `Button` react on a change to the bound objects change

```
<Button ToolTip="{Binding Tip}" 
        ib:ButtonProperties.Image="{Binding EnabledSource}" 
        ib:ButtonDProperties.Image="{Binding DisabledSource}" 
        Content="{Binding Text}" 
        IsEnabled="{Binding DefaultEnabled}"
        Tag="{Binding .}"

        Click="ToolBarButtonButton_Click"

        Style="{StaticResource ImageButton}">

</Button>
```

For simplification purposes, Lets say, I  databind a collections of Custom objects which Have a Property called "IsPerfect" of type bool. The Object assigned to the button is set as the tag as well.

I would like to have the button reacting on the property "IsPerfect" that belongs to the databound object and then execute a eventhandler or enable/disable the button.

Comment: `I have a control that has a datacontext being loaded and based on it I create a bunch of buttons` - That's called an `ItemsControl`, you know.

Comment: i use it. I was just leaving unneccesarry inf. ;) 
thnx anyway

Answer (score 1):

```
<Button IsEnabled="{Binding SomeBoolValue}"/>
```

Comment: How is 2 way binding supposed to work on a read-only property? This means, the user is unable to manually change the IsEnabled status. It's not like `TextBox.Text`, if you see what I mean.

Comment: tried it, doesn't work. Had it already in my example I gave. setting the propery "DefaultEnabled" does not enable the button.

Comment: @user853710 Have you implemented the `INotifyPropertyChanged` in your custom object?

Comment: No. still learning WPF. Something I will look into. If you can provide me with a a good article, I'd be gratefull

Comment: @user853710 Post a screenshot of what you need and I can tell you the proper way to do it in WPF.

Comment: I think that INotifyPropertyChanged looks like it might be the right way to go. Thanks

Comment: @user853710 Here is a **[link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/100175/Model-View-ViewModel-MVVM-Explained)** which introduces the MVVM design pattern in WPF. I think it would be quite helpful for you. :)

Comment: thnks. Solved it with INotified . ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a style to fulfill your goal.

```
<Button>
  <Button.Style>
   <Style>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPerfect}" Value="True">
         <Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="True"></Setter>
      </DataTrigger>
   </Style>
  <Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: how to add this properly to the template that I am loading. The copy/paste of the datatrigger does not work. I suposse because of the binding.